# Redirect to Account/Login view in asp.net core 7, from an anonymous action method of a controller

Tags: asp.net-core

Home/Index is my default route of asp.net core application. In this method "index" of controller "Home", I need to check if the user is signed in or not, if the user is signed in, the user will be redirected to a special page according to role of the user.
In other case, the user will be redirected to login page.

But login page is not being displayed and also not being shown any error message like the page is not found.

I tried following different options after studying articles in stackoverflow and other sites

```
return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account", new {area = "Identity"});
return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account", new {area = ""});
return RedirectToAction("Login", "Identity/Account", new {area = ""});
return Redirect("/Account/Login");
```

But if applied `[Authorize]` attribute, then `Account/Login` page is being shown. So please guide me how to handle this scenario.

Following is given the complete flow and logic

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    if (_userManager.IsSignedIn(User))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("MyDetails", "SupAdmin");
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account", new {area = "Identity"});
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account", new {area = ""});
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Identity/Account", new {area = ""});
        return Redirect("/Account/Login");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can set the breakpoint at the `if `and `else` to see where it goes. "But login page is not being displayed and also not being shown any error message like the page is not found." What the page you see ? Could you share it?

Answer (score 2):

i hope this is what you want to do, but since i think i was in the same issue as you here you go:

If you want to call, for example "Login.cshtml" or "Register.cshtml" from a own Controller (example: HomeController) you need to return the View() instead of redirecting to it. Here is some code for explanation:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return View("/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Register.cshtml");
    }
```

This function gets Called when the user clicks a button by an Ajax.Post. After that redirects to Identity/Register View. Make sure to check the route of the view, yours might be different from mine.

Answer (score 1):

I try the below code, then it displays the login view:

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }
```

Comment: In my case, it is not working. I am using asp.net core 7

Comment: What the page you see ? Could you share it?

Comment: I see a blank page, nothing to view, not any error, just blank page